# how to make phone number mask on Django?

Tags: python, django, mask, digits

Lets say i have a phone number like:

> 05395042123

I want to convert it to a format like :

> xxxx xxx xx xx

How am I going to do that? Anyone have a function?

Comment: And what happens when someone who's not from your country tries to use your site?

Comment: its a local site for now i will find a solution later.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's very easy to do it by hand, which is probably the best idea as long as you have only one format:

```
def phone_split(x):
  return ' '.join([x[0:4], x[4:7], x[7:9], x[9:]])
```

**EDIT:**

And a more universal way:

```
def phone_split(x, format=[4,3,2,2]):
  parts = []
  reduce(lambda x, y: parts.append(x[:y]) or x[y:], format, x)
  return ' '.join(parts)
```

It's using `append()` side effect to accumulate a result and an `or` to meet a lambda's *one-liner* requirment.

**EDIT2:**

I've just realized that you probably want to use that inside a Django Template. If that's the case you probably want to use code above to define a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) and [register it as a simple filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#registering-custom-filters).

Answer (score -1):

```
def mask_mobile_number(self,obj):
  return "XXXXXX{}".format(str(obj.mobile_number)[6:])
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.